# Flattening a Column of Nested JSON objects

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas

I exported a `csv` from `MongoDB` into a `Python` `Pandas` `DataFrame`. However, my efforts to flatten a particular column - containing nested data - has proven futile.

The standard function (as far as I can tell) that should have extracted the columns of values is returning an error. That function is `json_normalize` from the `pandas.io.json` library. And the error returned is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Upon further examination, I can see that if I am to print the column, it is not nested the way that the `json_normalize` function requires. In the [docs pertaining to that function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html), the `data` parameter requires an `Unserialized JSON object`,  the docs describe it as looking like this:

```
data = [{'id': 1, 'name': {'first': 'Coleen', 'last': 'Volk'}},
        {'name': {'given': 'Mose', 'family': 'Regner'}},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'Faye Raker'}]
```

However, 2 rows from the column of my data look like this:

```
[{"name":"A","size":"","price":300,"quantity":0,"_id":"9574"},  {"name":"B","size":"","price":400,"quantity":0,"_id":"1345"}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[{"name":"C","size":"","price":300,"quantity":0,"_id":"0596"},{"size":"","price":400,"quantity":0,"_id":"0931","name":"D"}]
```

If it is not clear from the description of my data, basically, each row within the column is contained within square brackets, furthermore, all of the rows are not contained within one set of outer square brackets, and each set of curly brackets is not 'comma'd' from the next set of curly brackets.

I can remove all of these outer square brackets, from each cell using a `regex` function, however the `json_normalize` function returns the same error.

Importing the dataset as a `JSON` file, instead of as a `csv` does not change anything either. I still get the same error.

It's not obvious to me how to format the entire column, so that it looks the way `json_normalize` requires.

Comment: How exactly are you using `json_normalize`? It sounds like you are giving it a string, when it expects a dict or list of dicts ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)). One way around this is to convert your input string to JSON using `json.loads`. For example: `import json; data = json.loads(your_string); json_normalize(data)`.